# Xamarin : How should I use LogNetworkRequest in Crittercism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, crittercism

I am using HttpClient in my Xamarin app. Using Crittercism for Instrumentation.  I tried using LogNetworkRequest in Crittercism but I am not sure how to use it.

```
Crittercism.LogNetworkRequest(
"GET",
"http://www.abc123def456.com",
2000,                                      // latency in milliseconds
10000,                                     // bytesRead
100,                                       // bytesSent
HttpStatusCode.OK,
WebExceptionStatus.Success);
```

How should I set parameters like Latency, BytesRead,BytesSent?

This is my code which makes call to REST

```cs
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var httpResponseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request,cancellationToken);
}
```

The question is how to hook up call to LogNetworkRequest in my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a StopWatch to record latency. For recording BytesSent and Received used following code:

```cs
var requestBytes = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ();
networkRequestInfo.BytesSent = requestBytes.Length;
```